# Angular unit test how to test a routerLink

Tags: angular, unit-testing

How to test a routerLink ?

I tried with

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    debugEl = fixture.debugElement;
    element = debugEl.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  it('should have href with /login', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const href = debugEl.query(By.css('a')).nativeElement.getAttribute('href');
    console.error(href) // give me null 
    //expect(expect(href)).toEqual('/login');
  });
```

But the href var is null. 
I also tried with .nativeElement.href
and give me a void string

Comment: Have you imported the RoutingModule into your test module?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In order for `routerLink` directive to be compiled, router module (more specifically, its test variety, because real routing shouldn't occur in tests) should be imported to test bed:

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

...

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [RouterTestingModule]
});
```

Considering that there is `<a routerLink="/login"></a>` in component template, this should be true:

```
const href = debugEl.query(By.css('a')).nativeElement.getAttribute('href');
expect(expect(href)).toEqual('/login');
```

Considering that `routerLink` accepts complex configurations, `href` assertion may be not enough. Even though it relies on `RouterTestingModule` that should be trusted, it's black box test.

A more specific way is to test `routerLink` input itself. Considering that there is `<a [routerLink]="['/login']"></a>` in component template and `RouterTestingModule` was imported as well, this should be true:

```
import { RouterLinkWithHref } from '@angular/router';

...

const linkDebugEl = debugEl.query(By.css('a'));
const routerLinkInstance = linkDebugEl.injector.get(RouterLinkWithHref);
expect(routerLinkInstance['commands']).toEqual(['/login']);
expect(routerLinkInstance['href']).toEqual('/login');
```

This doesn't require `RouterTestingModule`; `RouterLink` directive can be replaced with appropriate dummy directive if necessary to test `commands` input.

Answer (score 3):

You need to spy on the Router.

```
const router = TestBed.get(router); //Get the router from the TestBed.
const spy = spyOn(router, 'navigate'); //Register a Spy on the router navigate function

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['login']); //Check if the router has been called with 'login'
```

Also you should be using the RouterTestingModule in your tests rather than using the application one.

[Router Testing Module](https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule)

You can set it up with your own routes if you need to. (from the Angular testing Documentation)

```
 beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestModule({
    imports: [
      RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
       [{path: '', component: BlankCmp}, {path: 'simple', component: SimpleCmp}])]
      )
    ]
  });
});
```

See more information on [Angular Testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing)